# Nginx connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.128.1, server: hello-1.local

Tags: nginx, ssl, docker, reverse-proxy

I am trying to setup ssl on my django + docker + nginx environment. However I encountered this error:

> *19 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.128.1, server: hello-1.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://192.168.128.4:443/", host: "hello-1.local"

My Nginx config:

```
client_max_body_size 10M;

upstream web {  
  ip_hash;
  server web:443;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name hello-1.local;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {    
    
    location /static/ {    
        autoindex on;    
        alias /src/static/; 
    }

    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /src/media/;
    }

``

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://web/;
    }
    
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name hello-1.local;
    ssl_certificate /etc/certs/hello-1.local.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/certs/hello-1.local.key;
    
}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nz01
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./config/certs:/etc/certs
    depends_on:
      - web
    networks:
      - djangonetwork
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: compose/django/Dockerfile
    container_name: dz01
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
    expose:
      - 8000
    links:
      - redis
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.django
    networks:
      - djangonetwork
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: compose/postgres/Dockerfile
    container_name: pz01
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.postgres
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    networks:
      - djangonetwork
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: rz01
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - djangonetwork

networks:
  djangonetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

In browser, I get 502 Bad Gateway error and without ssl, the website run well. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what is the upstream?

The upstream is defined here:

```
upstream web {  
  ip_hash;
  server web:443;
}
```

My first reading of this is, that the Nginx cannot properly connect to the upstream-server named `web`.

This can have multiple reasons:

- your Nginx can't resolve `web`
- the webserver running on `web` is not serving https/port 443
- the webserver running on `web` does not use a valid and trusted certificate for the hostname `web`

Taking a look at your docker-compose.yml:

- the application `web` is exposed to port 8000, but you want to connect to port 443 in Nginx, also using the wrong protocol (I guess)

So the solution would be to change you upstream-config in nginx.conf like this:

```
upstream web {  
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}
```

and the location-block like this (https --> http):

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://web/;
}
```

Regarding SSL/TLS with proxies/upstreams:
Please take a look into Nginx-docs around this: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_verify

Comment: It looks like `web` is the Django app listening on port 8000. No surprise that trying to connect to it on port 443 doesn't work!

Comment: You're right! I didn't look properly at the compose-file but only on the nginx-config. Will edit my answer.

Comment: I got it working by changing the upstream config and location block according to your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @ppuschmann  I have the same kind of issue https://serverfault.com/questions/1098225/connection-refused-while-connecting-to-nginx-in-docker-container . Its not working with http too. Can you have a look into this question

Comment: @imhans4305 would have done so, if you hadn't removed the question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup in my Web application where Nginx is a reverse proxy for Dockerized Django and React. I'm also using a self-signed certificate for SSL in local development.

I was having a difficult time because React (Next.js) is fetching data from Django's REST API--- but some request are coming from the server while others are coming from the client. Server-based request were able to use `http://backend:8000` (the Docker service name and exposed port), but client-based requests needed to go through `https://example.local`.

If anyone is stuck on this and using Swagger UI (i.e., drf-yasg), this was my Achilles' heel--- you NEED to configure the OpenAPI "DEFAULT_API_URL". If you have a self-signed SSL certificate with `example.local`, you should setup `https://example.local` as your Swagger URL. With `drf-yasg`, here is my `settings.py`:

```python
# Swagger
ENDPOINT_DOMAIN = "https://example.com"
if DEBUG:
    ENDPOINT_DOMAIN = "https://example.local"
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
        'basic': {
            'type': 'basic'
        }
    },
    'DEFAULT_API_URL': ENDPOINT_DOMAIN,
}
```

Additionally, I had to match this in my Next.js config (`next.config.js`):

```javascript
const nextConfig = {
  ...
  assetPrefix: 'https://example.local',
  ...
}
```

Finally, my Nginx config looks like this:

```bash
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name example.local;
  return 302 https://example.local$request_uri;
}

# Main server directive
server {
  http2               on;

  listen 443          default ssl;
  listen [::]:443     default ssl;

  ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certs/example.test.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/example.test.key;

  root                /app;
  server_name         example.local;

  charset utf-8;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_min_length 1100;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/rss+xml
    image/svg+xml;

  # Setup frontend requests to use port 3000
  location @frontend {
    internal;
    root       /app/frontend/;
    proxy_pass http://frontend:3000;

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy     true;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme      $scheme;
  }

  # Setup backend requests to use port 8000
  location @backend {
    proxy_pass http://backend:8000;

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_ssl_verify off;
    proxy_set_header Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy     true;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme      $scheme;
  }

  # Frontend =============================================
  location / {
    try_files $uri @frontend;
  }

  location ~ ^/assets/(.*)$ {
    root      /app/frontend/public/;
    try_files $uri @frontend;
  }

  location ~ ^/favicon(.*)$ {
    root      /app/frontend/public/assets/favicon/;
    try_files $uri @frontend;
  }

  location ~ ^/_next/(.*)$ {
    root      /app/frontend/;
    try_files $uri @frontend;
  }

  location /_next/webpack-hmr {
    root      /app/frontend/;
    try_files $uri @frontend;

    # Websockets
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  }

  location /404 {
    try_files $uri @frontend;
  }


  # Backend ===============================================
  location ~ ^/swagger(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri @backend;
  }

  location ~ ^/redoc(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri @backend;
  }

  location ~ ^/admin(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri @backend;
  }

  location ~ ^/api(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri @backend;
  }

  location ~ ^/webmention(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri @backend;
  }

  location ~ ^/rss(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri @backend;
  }

  location /sitemap.xml {
    try_files $uri @backend;
  }

  location ~ ^/static/(.*)$ {
    root      /app/backend/;
    try_files $uri @backend;

    autoindex on;
  }

  location ~ ^/uploads/(.*)$ {
    root      /app/backend/;
    try_files $uri @backend;
  }

  location /(500|502|503|504) {
    try_files $uri @backend;
  }

  # Error handling
  error_page 404 /404;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500;
}
```